# convert json to highcharts standard multiple series

Tags: json, highcharts

I have data from my db that i convert to json as the following

```
[{"name":"partner1","cost":"311328","date":"2013-04-01"},
{"name":"partner1","cost":"363780","date":"2013-04-02"},
{"name":"partner1","cost":"364062","date":"2013-04-03"},
{"name":"partner1","cost":"283128","date":"2013-04-04"},
{"name":"partner1","cost":"322608","date":"2013-04-05"},
{"name":"partner2","cost":"425538","date":"2013-04-01"},
{"name":"partner2","cost":"263670","date":"2013-04-02"},
{"name":"partner2","cost":"213192","date":"2013-04-03"},
{"name":"partner2","cost":"378726","date":"2013-04-04"},
{"name":"partner2","cost":"532698","date":"2013-04-05"}]
```

How will be the best wat to convert this json data into highcharta standard for multiple series data?

My last resort is to do multiple query to db to construct the data, but i think it will comnsume server time resource.

Appreciate for the help.

regards,

Comment: Is each distinct partner supposed to give one series, or what?

Comment: yes @john, 1 partner for 1 series

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally you'd transform the data to look like this:

```
{"partner1": [
  [Date.UTC(2013,3,1), 311328],
  [Date.UTC(2013,3,2), 363780],
...
```

Note that the month argument to Javascript's Date function starts from 0 (January).

Comment: By writing code.  Why don't you try it and let us know how it goes?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should use timestamp as dates (i.e by Date.UTC() ), morever values should be number, not string.